# ruby puts get stuck adding unix content

Tags: ruby, stdout

My ruby puts get stuck for some reason and i cant figure out why,
The commands i'm passing through the backticks are alright, the script gets stuck between the puts 2 and puts 2 commands, so it basically never exits the puts command containing the unix sort / cut
    #!/usr/bin/ruby/

```
require 'fileutils'

@raw_file=File.open(ARGV[0],"r") unless File.open(ARGV[0],"r").nil?
#agg_file=File.open(ARGV[1],"r") unless File.open(ARGV[1],"r").nil?
@pwd=Dir.pwd
puts @pwd
#do the raw file first
 def do_raw
  tmp_raw=File.new("#{@pwd}/tmp_raw","w")
  #unix cut and sort
  puts 1
  tmp_raw.puts(`cat #{@raw_file} | cut -f1,6,3,4,2,5,9,12 | sort -k1,1 -k8,8`)
  puts 2
  tmp_raw.close
  tmp_raw=File.open("#{@pwd}/tmp_raw","r")
  final_file=File.new("#{@pwd}/uniques_raw","w")
    #merge the lines and append count
    vector =IO.readlines(@tmp_raw.path)[1]
    count=1
     while (line=tmp_raw.gets) do
       if line.eql? vector
          count=count+1
       else
          vector=line
          final_file.write("#{line}\t#{count}")
          count=1
       end
     end
     #job done, close and clean file
     tmp_raw.close
     final_file.close
     tmp_raw.remove
 end

#run jobs
 do_raw
```

But a simple:
    tmp_raw.puts("blablabla")
Works, so the file is ok

The puts command get stuck, i have tryed the simple command on terminal and it works just fine, the files are also existing and writing some random text into them works just fine
Any idea?

Comment: I guess `tmp_raw.close` will probably flush the contents ?

Comment: thx but unfortunatelly it does not, it really never comes out of the puts command, i have added a puts "2" command that never prints....

Comment: What is `@raw_puts`. It should be `@raw_file`

Comment: sorry that was my wrong copy paste, i have modified it, thx

Comment: and do you still have the problem after fixing the variable name? because that sure looked like the source of the problem.

Comment: well the variable name was never wrong, it was a mistak i made here in the text area when cutting the code.

Comment: With the right variable name, I am unable to reproduce any problem..

Comment: i have just pasted the real code,

Comment: Can you insert `puts @raw_file.to_r` and ``puts `cat #{@raw_file}`.to_r`` before `puts 1` and try again?

Comment: to_r is undefined for File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see. `@raw_file` is a `File` object rather than the file name itself.  Then you cannot invoke the `cat(1)` command against the string representation of the `File` object.

You should have wrote

```
tmp_raw.puts(`cat #{ARGV[0]} | cut -f1,6,3,4,2,5,9,12 | sort -k1,1 -k8,8`)
```

Comment: Hi Nodakai, you were right thx! i have solved it with cat #{@raw_file.path} , thx for your precious advice!